# Highlighting a selected sheet in Rstudio scripting pane? [images included]

Tags: r, themes, rstudio

Suppose I am scripting on the sheet BVR_STEP1.R, how can I change the settings so that it's clear to me what sheet in currently on?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Rstudio has it set up like a web browser, where the current tab is the same color as the toolbar below, the unused tabs are a darker color.

[RStudio has an IDE cheatsheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/rstudio-ide.pdf) to give you some keyboard shortcuts to switch between tabs a little easier for your user experience.

[image]